# Riemann integrable function and density in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Although I have searched the forum far and wide, I have not been able to find the following question: how can I prove that the Riemann integrable functions on $I=[a,b]$ are dense in $L^p(I)$ for $p\in [1,\infty)$?

Here's what ingredients I have:

> $1.$ $C_0(I)$ is dense in $L^p(I)$,$p\in[1,\infty)$, where $C_0(I)$ is the space of continuous
> function with compact support.

> $2.$ $C_0(I)\subseteq \mathcal{R}(I)\subseteq L^p(I)$, where $p\in [1,\infty)$, $C(I)$ denotes the space of continuous function on $I$ and $\mathcal{R}(I)$ is the space of Riemann integrable function on $I$.

Could you please help me solve this problem? Could you please provide me with a detailed answer? Thank you.

**$\Large$ My Solution**

Let $f\in L^p(I)$, then exists $\{f_n\}\subseteq C_0(I)$ such that $$f_n\to f\quad \text{in}\; L^p(I).$$

Since $C_0(I)\subseteq \mathcal{R}(I)$ results that $\mathcal{R}(I)$ is dense in $L^p(I)$. Correct?

Comment: What can you say about $C_0(I)$ and $C(I)$?

Comment: @BrunoBI know that $C_0(I)\subseteq C(I)$

Comment: So what can you deduce from $C_0(I) \subset \mathcal{R}(I) \subset L^p(I)$ and $\overline{C_0(I)} = L^p(I)$ ?

Comment: @BrunoBI followed your suggestion. I wrote my solution. Does it seem correct to you?

Comment: Your solution works indeed.